# How to set all-day date value in a Rules Component

Tags: 7, rules

I have a node with a Date field set to February 8th, 2020 but when I try to set a Date Value as 'Data to Compare' but the date/hour keeps changing. How do I set the data value for all day?

Drupal 7.69
Rules 7.x-2.12

[image: Data Value in Rules]

Comment: to compare 2 dates in rules or components, first convert them as an integer (unix time stamp)

Comment: So, the date field on the Content type needs to be a unix time stamp version of the field?

Comment: no, inside your rule or component: add an action: convert a data type, your date(s) field(s) to integer, that gives you a unix time stamp stored in a variable, and if you wish, you can substract variables (or whatever), then result may be converted to date format with: convert a data type action.